# Making snake in java

Tags: java

When we want to go up why are we using this:

```
if (up == true)
    yCoor--;
```

Instead of this:

```
if (up == true)
   yCoor++;
```

If you want the full code ask in the comments, I hope this is enough

Comment: Depends entirely which graphics API you're using. Some consider `y = 0` to mean the top of the screen, some consider it to mean the bottom of the screen, some even consider it to mean the center of the screen :)

Comment: Anyway... Consider to use if(up) yCoor--; Instead of if(up == true) yCoor--;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because y-axis in this field traditionally directed from top of screen to bottom.

Reason behind it is purely historical. In monitors beam scan screen from top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D matrix is named using the following convention

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) ... 
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) ...
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) ...
...
```

where the first digit is the y co-ordinate. So to move up the matrix you have to decrease the yCoor.